# Running batch files with updated properties values

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, properties

I am completely lost on how to do this...so some help would be nice. So i've created a batch file with my java program (uses a query to collect some data and output it as a CSV file). I also have a properties file so that i can change the parameters of the query.

My batch file runs and executes my code but the problem is, that when i update my query parameters in my properties file to get different results, my batch file does not run with the updated values but just the old ones.

```
title sender
echo@ off
java -jar "googleanalyticsfile.jar"
```

Here is what i have in my bat file, any help would be nice thx

EDIT:

so here is my query in the java file

```
private static GaData executeDataQuery(Analytics analytics, String metrics, String dimensions, String startDate, String endDate, String sort, String profileID) throws IOException {
    return analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileID, // Table Id. ga: + profile id.
        startDate, // Start date.
        endDate, // End date.
        metrics) // Metrics.
        .setDimensions(dimensions)
        .setSort(sort)
        .setMaxResults(100)//this value needs to be an int not string
        .execute();
```

Here is where i initialize the parameters for my query
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
 try {
      ...some code
      //stuff imported from properties file
      CrunchifyGetPropertyValues metricValues = new CrunchifyGetPropertyValues();
      String metrics = metricValues.metrics();
      String dimensions = metricValues.dimensions();
      String startDate = metricValues.startDate();
      String endDate = metricValues.endDate();
      String sort = metricValues.sort();
      String profileID = metricValues.profileID();
      if (profileID == null) {
        System.err.println("No profiles found.");
      } else {
        GaData gaData = executeDataQuery(analytics, metrics, dimensions, startDate, endDate, sort, profileID);
        printGaData(gaData);
      }
```

EDIT:

```
public class CrunchifyGetPropertyValues {

        public String metrics() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String Metrics = prop.getProperty("Metrics");

            result = Metrics;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        public String dimensions() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String Dimensions = prop.getProperty("Dimensions");

            result = Dimensions;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        public String startDate() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String startDate = prop.getProperty("startDate");

            result = startDate;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        public String endDate() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String endDate = prop.getProperty("endDate");

            result = endDate;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        public String sort() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String sort = prop.getProperty("sort");

            result = sort;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        public String maxResults() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String maxResults = prop.getProperty("maxResults");

            result = maxResults;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        public String profileID() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String profileID = prop.getProperty("profileID");

            result = profileID;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    and i call the properties file by each string does that help at all?

    EDIT:

    public class CrunchifyGetPropertyValues {

        public String metrics() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String Metrics = prop.getProperty("Metrics");

            result = Metrics;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        public String dimensions() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String Dimensions = prop.getProperty("Dimensions");

            result = Dimensions;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        public String startDate() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String startDate = prop.getProperty("startDate");

            result = startDate;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        public String endDate() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String endDate = prop.getProperty("endDate");

            result = endDate;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        public String sort() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String sort = prop.getProperty("sort");

            result = sort;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        public String maxResults() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String maxResults = prop.getProperty("maxResults");

            result = maxResults;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
        public String profileID() throws IOException {

            String result = "";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";

            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            prop.load(inputStream);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String profileID = prop.getProperty("profileID");

            result = profileID;       
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Yea...a lot of code probably could be condensed but thats whats in my CrunchifyGetPropertyValues

Comment: I don't see you specifying location of the properties file anywhere in this batch script.  Post the code that reads the properties file from java

Comment: hmm i've copied the query and the way that it calls the properties in the java still no clue on how to link them. so basically i want the batch files to run the most up to date properties file with the query

Comment: Show us the place where you initialize parameters that to pass to `executeDataQuery`

Comment: posted any more advice to figure out the issue?..i am really new to batch scripting

Comment: Now, finally, get us the source code for `CrunchifyGetPropertyValues`.  And, BTW, that would be a code that "reads the properties file from java".

Comment: alright posted lol phew lots of posting...honestly any advice even to point me in the right direction would help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a smoking gun:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
```

You are loading properties file from inside the `jar` file.

A file on disk never comes under consideration.

You have to provide a full path to alternate properties file either as an argument to the `main` method, or as a system property.

BTW, you better check if `inputStream` is not `null` before `prop.load` call.